# Is it possible to have Jython use Unix Sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, jython, unix-socket

In Jython 2.7:

```
>>>import socket
>>>print socket.AF_UNIX
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'
```

I'm trying to use Pyro4 with Jython to connect to a NameServer running on a unix socket. The code for Pyro4 under the hood looks similar to this:

```
family = socket.AF_UNIX
sock = socket.socket(family, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(name)
```

However, I receive the `'module' object has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'` error.

A Jython [bug report](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2265) suggests this isn't supported out of the box.

Is it possible to get this working?

Comment: You'll probably have to use a Java library for it for now.

Comment: See the note in [`socket.AF_UNIX`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.AF_UNIX).  "If the `AF_UNIX` constant is not defined then this protocol is unsupported."  Since the JVM is meant to be cross-platform, and Unix domain sockets don't exist on Windows, it is unlikely Jython has any out-of-the-box support for said sockets.

Comment: @Kevin: Jython implements many other things that are neither cross-platform nor in the JVM, like the whole `os` module with things such as `stat`, `symlink`, `chmod`, `kill`, &c&c. It wouldn't necessarily be unexpected to see the `socket` module implement Unix sockets. That said, the `socket` module also goes rather far to use Java sockets in order to be compatible with other Java libraries, so that's likely the reason.